# How to have Propel ORM 1.6 created_at fields?

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

I tried to specify this field:

```
<column name="created_at" phpName="CreatedAt" type="TIMESTAMP" required="false"/>
```

However, whether it's required or not, Propel never seems to place the current date time on it. How do I specify that I want Propel to take care of this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [timestampable behavior](http://www.propelorm.org/behaviors/timestampable.html):

> The `timestampable` behavior allows you to keep track of the date of creation and last update of your model objects.

Using (by default):

```
<behavior name="timestampable" />
```

Or (if you want to customize field):

```
<behavior name="timestampable">
  <parameter name="create_column" value="my_create_date" />
  <parameter name="update_column" value="my_update_date" />
</behavior>
```